# How to count items join it and paginate?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to count some items from the `table` and `join` it with the another `table` so I use the following code

```
Article::join("article_comments", "article_comments.article_id", "=","articles.id")->
select(["articles.title", "articles.content", "articles.created_at", DB::raw('count(article_comments.id) as commentsCount')])->paginate(10) ;
```

But I always get only first item

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't there be a group by if you use aggregates?

Something like:

```
Article::join("article_comments", "article_comments.article_id", "=","articles.id")->
    select(["articles.title", "articles.content", "articles.created_at", DB::raw('count(article_comments.id) as commentsCount')])->
    groupBy('articles.id')->
    paginate(10);
```

Also since you're no using your joined table for filtering you might wanna consider eager loading. However in your case you only get articles with comments. When using eager loading you'd get all articles (including the ones without comments).

Something like that should work:

```
Article::with([
    'comments' => function ($query) {
        $query
            ->select('article_id', DB::raw('COUNT(`id`) AS `commentCount`'))
            ->groupBy('article_id')
    }
])
    ->paginate(10);
```

Now you should be able to access the count like this:

```
echo $article->comments->first()->commentCount;
```

Did not test the solution. You might wanna check if $article->comments->first() exists.

Or if you wanna expand your model a little [here](http://laravel.io/forum/05-03-2014-eloquent-get-count-relation) are some even better thoughts

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your answer could you give me an example, please?

Comment: thank you, your solution doesn't work but the link you gave me helped me to find the solution.